# Collapsed and collapsible Field Sets in Admin

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a fieldset (which groups a field collection). Because it has a few nested levels and many fields, I want it to be shown collapsed. I am trying this code but it does not work. The **id** is retrieved directly from the source code of the web browser. The fieldset is the top-level, and there are more fieldsets inside of it. The form is displayed in the Admin page, the node edit form. The field "field-seo-general" is a #container.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == "my_form"){
        $form["field-seo-general"]['options']['attributes']["#collapsible"] = TRUE;
        $form["field-seo-general"]['options']['attributes']["#collapsed"] = TRUE;
      ...
} // function
```

Comment: I don't have time to test this out myself, but try adding the classes "collapsible" and "collapsed" to your field_seo_general field. so something like `$form['field_seo_general']['attributes']['class'][] = 'collapsible';` etc. **Edit:** If that doesn't work, try taking out `['options']['attributes']` in each line.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved at high level with module Field Collection Fieldset.

Comment: I tested by removing options and attributes. I will try later your option and compare with what the module does.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it installing the module [Field Collection Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_fieldset), and instead of Embedding the Field Collection, I have put it as a Fieldset, and then one of the options is to be shown Collapsed at rendering. All with a module.

Answer (score 0):

> The field "field-seo-general" is a #container.

The [The Form API entry for `container`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#container) does not include [`#collapsed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsed) or [`#collapsible`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsible) as properties.

It seems that [`fieldset`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#fieldset) is the only element that can use the [`#collapsed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsed) and [`#collapsible`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsible) properties.

Change the `#type` for `field-seo-general` to `fieldset` to make it collapsible. If `field-seo-general` needs to be a `container`, then a second option would be to create a `fieldset` and place the `field-seo-general` container within it. However, doing this will add one more dimension within the `values` array for your fields when the form is submitted, so you need to take that into account.

```
$container_seo_general = $form['field_seo_general'];
unset($form['field_seo_general']);
$fieldset = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'My fieldset title',
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
);
$fieldset['field_seo_general'] = $container_seo_general;
$form['my_module_fieldset'] = $fieldset;
```